# Can "in front of" be used as a time adverbial?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbials

At my workplace, which is a large multinational corporation with a non-English speaking headquarter, I often hear "in front of" being used in the meaning "before".

Some examples:
"Prepare the backlog in front of the planning event."
"Get a chance to meet your colleagues in front of the summer holiday."

I have never heard "in front of" being used in this way outside this company and I wonder if it could be considered grammatically correct. The phrase is used by many people throughout the organization so it's not just a small group of people who started speaking this way. The company is known for the peculiar English accent that is shared by many senior managers and comes from the city's local accent and non-native English. This usage of "in front of" has no connection to the local language so it must have some other origin.

Comment: Regular English it's not. The French *en face* means in front of, before, facing, opposite, and such.

Comment: But this is how in-group lects form. If your peers in the speech community talk that way, you should, too. It's more important to be accepted as a member than to think your speech is superior.

Comment: Thank you @YosefBaskin, there is a large French community in the company so that's probably where it originates from. Funny how it spreads to other nationalities.

Comment: It's not _grammatically_ incorrect, it's just not what a native speaker would say.

Comment: It's not common, but I'm pretty sure I've heard it numerous times.